# how to use c++ to do data acquisition from frame grabber

Tags: c++, camera, frame

We have an "MC1362 Camera" and an "Inspecta-5" frame grabber in our lab. There is program in LABVIEW11 which gets the data from a frame grabber, however as the Labview is slow my supervisor has told me to write a program in c++ to get the data from the frame grabber. I have no idea how to write a c++ program to connect to a frame grabber and do the data acquisition. I know how to write software in c++, but have never tried programming to connect to hardware and read data from it. Is there any specific library or framework which can help me, or any tutorial?
Please, if anybody knows, help me in this matter.

**Update**:just to add, we are doing medical image analysis, and a laser illuminate a subject, so camera will take pictures and pass it to the computer. I need to grab the pictures and analysis them.

Comment: I would start by talking to the manufacturer of the Inspecta-5, or looking on their web site.

Comment: hi leondro, all the camera and framgrabber drivers are based on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have a couple of options,

1 see if there is an SDK for the grabber card, if there is this is usually easier then option 2 but is of course restricted to work with that grabber or familly of grabber cards, we do it this way with the eurysys grabber cards.

2 assuming you are running on a windows platform, implement a DirectShow filtergraph and write your own ouput filter to get the data, the SDK for DirectShow is quiet good and has many examples.  This approach is far more flexible and you should be able to use a number of grabber but its also alot more complex, we do it this way for USB / some other inbuilt grabbers.

Our software is done in Delphi 7 but its just importing DLLs, for C++ should be no problem and most SDK's are written round C++ anyway.

I know its not much but its a place to start.

**Update**
Just done a quick Google search and there is an SDK for that Grabber and on first looks its seams fairly straight forward.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your answer, I searched on internet and found HALCON 10 interface supporting Inspecta-5, but unfortunately it seems an expensive interface, I was wondering have you found anything else? please let me know. THANK YOU.

Comment: I just googled for "Inspecta-5 SDK" but here is a link to there dowloads page http://www.mikrotron.de/index.php?en_downloadfiles